# Docker daemon error failing to resolve reference

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-registry, docker-daemon

i updated docker desktop today and now i can't run anything anymore with the following errors:

```
MBP:basic_amethyst ap$ botfront up
⠋ Checking Docker images┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│error: 'Error: Command failed: docker   pull mongo:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│Error response from daemon: failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/mongo:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/mongo/manifests/latest": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:3128: connect: connection refused                        │
│' stdout = '' stderr = 'Error response from daemon: failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/mongo:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/mongo/manifests/latest": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:3128: connect: connection refused│
│'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
✖ Could not download Docker images
```

This happened while i was trying to run botfront for rasa chatbot!

I also get the an error when running `docker login` (and yes i entered the correct credentials):

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:3128: connect: connection refused
```

Here the infos to my system:

docker --version - Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701 |
Docker Desktop 4.12.0 (85629) is currently the newest version available. |
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019,....) | Private device so no company proxy | logged in via docker desktop

And this is what i tried so far:

- restarting / shutting down and booting up again the device
- setting the experimental to false
- uninstalled docker and docker gui and reinstalled them

Any suggestions? Thinking of downgrading to previous (working) version as last resort. Thanks!

Comment: `dial tcp 172.17.0.1:3128: connect: connection refused` sounds like an issue with a local HTTP proxy connection, not anything in your application source code.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling everything docker related solved it for me!